# access violation When Form2 trying to edit form1 In delphi

Tags: forms, delphi, access-violation

For example when I'm trying to do something like this

```
form2.Edit1.text=form1.edit1.text
```

It gives me an access violation error.

The way form2 can use form1 variables is by adding

```
uses Unit1; var Form1:Tform1
```

to the implementation

The program compiles fine with no errors but when trying to actually access the edit1 from form1 it crashes with an error.

edit:

It seems like it is working when I'm adding unit1 to the "uses" list not under implementation but under interface

which means unit2 can edit unit1 but I cant add now unit2 to the uses of interface of unit1
circular unit reference

In short it meant

- unit2 can edit/view unit1
- unit1 cant edit/view unit2

So is there a way to make it possible without creating third frame which is refered by the two other units?

Comment: It seems like It is working when im adding unit1 to the "uses" list not under implementation but under interface

which means unit2 can edit unit1 but I cant add now unit2 to the uses of interface of unit1

In short it meant 

 - unit2 can edit/view unit1
 - unit1 cant edit/view unit2

So is there a way to make it possible?

Comment: As No'am Newman pointed out, make sure you are not redeclaring the Form1 variable. Also, check in Project->Options->Forms if you have both Form1 and Form2 in Auto-create forms list.

Answer (score 3):

You have two variables called `Form1` in your project. The code in the .dpr file creates a `TForm1` and saves the reference in **one** of the two `Form1` variables. You then are referring to the other unassigned `Form1`.

That explains why you are getting the access violation. How to fix it? Simply remove the `Form1` variable from `Unit2`. Use the Find in Files feature to make sure that you have only one declaration of `Form1`, `Form2` etc. in your entire project.

When you do that correctly you will have no trouble having each unit using the other, from the implementation section, with no circular reference problems.

In order to learn and understand this better I suggest you read the .dpr file to understand how the global variables are initialised. I also recommend that you read the Delphi language guide section on scope resolution to understand how the compiler resolves situations where two identical names are visible at the same location.

Comment: Agree. Personally i seldom let the .dpr initialize any other forms than the main form of the application. Other forms I initialize manually whenever they are needed. Also, I think i think it's good practice to not keep form variables as global variables, but to keep them as member variables of the other forms from which they are used.

Comment: @Elling I agree with that and do exactly the same. However, when explaining such things to a novice programmer it can be better to take small steps.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to declare form1 as a variable within form2 - there will be a global variable called 'form1'.

Comment: @HTxL: where exactly are you calling the code from?  Either the `Form1` or `Form2` pointer is invalid in that context.  Please show a more complete code snippet that shows what you are really doing.

Comment: @HTxL: where is form1 being instantiated? If it isn't the main form, you need to make sure it is instantiated before Form2 uses it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Put Unit1 under implementation, uses in Unit2.
Do not declare Form1 in Unit2. If you declare Form1 in Unit2, and don't assign it a value, it will be a null pointer giving an access violation when acccessed.
If you have freed Form1 or not created it it will also give access violation.

Answer (score 0):

THe fact that your project compiles means, that a variable "Form2" **is** declared and thus "known" to the compiler. The fact, that it gives a acces violation means, that there is no valid object assigned to this variable. There are a few possibilities. First, Form2 has to be created, by the IDE (auto-create the form in options of the project) or by your code. Second, there must not be a second variable called "Form2" which would "hide" the variable with the Form2-object.

You can and have to aviod having circular references in your uses-clauses. Use them in the "interface"-section if possible. Of course you can reference more than two units...

Comment: use them in the *implementation* section if possible?

Comment: @MGH: Or: *in the interface section if possible, in the implementation section when necessary*

Comment: @Marjan, Andreas I don't think this is correct.
If I make two units use each other in the interface section a circular reference is created. If they use each other via the implementation section it works.

Comment: @MGH: What we alluded to is that I usually have everything in the interface section's uses clause and only put units in the implementation section's uses clause to avoid the circular reference. Means you never create a circular reference without being made aware of it by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer for me was Adding unit1 to the interface of unit2 and add unit2 to the implementation of unit1

That is since unit1 is the main form and unit2 is opened by unit1.
so adding unit1 to the implementation of unit2 would not work.
It would've worked if both of the units were opened together.

Comment: Doesn't is this the same as Andreas had answered?